# How to Rotate Object 180 Degrees then Reset and Repeat Infinitely like a falling domino?

Tags: animation, edit-mode, keyframes, pose-mode

So I want to make this animation effect where the object falls forward 180 degrees on the x-axis, then right when it hits 180 degrees, it resets to the original position and falls forward again 180 degrees infinite times.

So starting position here

[image]

Then ends here

[image]

Then right when it rotates 180, it repeats the animation again as if it is continuously falling forward.

I only know how to do this with 360 degrees and adding #frame to the X axis in the transform tab, but not sure the word to use or method for only doing 180 degrees

Comment: hope you mean 90 degrees?

Comment: do you want your cube to move forwards (kind of roll) or just rotate forwards then rotate back to its original position (90° then -90°)?

Comment: sorry yes I mean 90 degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this as driver to your x location:

[image]

you can change the value 10 -> this determines the speed.

[image]

the driver only works correct if you have your pivot point of your block like this:

[image]

so the origin point of your block must be at the bottom of your block.

if you want the block to "fall" over the edge, set the pivot point like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: when I add the driver, it turns my object -90 then does the animation so its falling backwards? if I remove the minus sign, then it falls forwards, except my objects original position is set to -90 first. How do I make it start a 0 degree X axis?

Comment: oh if i delete the -(pi/2) part it starts at 0 then falls correctly, so it worked if i only typed (frame/10)%(pi/2)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want your object to roll forwards, if that's the case, the problem in Blender is that an object can't change its rotation center, it will always be its origin. But you can parent it to an empty and move and rotate the empty instead. There's a tool that makes it easy, it's the **[Dynamic Parent](https://github.com/romanvolodin/dynamic_parent/releases/tag/v1.0.0)** tool made by Roman Volodin.

Download and install the addon. Put the empty where the first rotation center is supposed to be (bottom of your cube), select the empty, shift select the cube, open the *N panel > Dynamic Parent >* click on *Create* (it will create a *Child Of* constraint for the cube). Create a keyframe for the empty, later on the *Dope Sheet* rotate it 90° and create a second keyframe, select the cube and click on *Dynamic Parent >Disable*. Move forward in the *Dope Sheet*, move the empty where the second rotation center is supposed to be, keyframe the empty, and again click select the cube, on *Create*, and so on:

[image]

[image]